# All other transforms disappear after broadcasting my custom odom to base_link transform (ROS2 Foxy)

Tags: python, ros

I have made a node to broadcast the odometry transform and publish the odometry topic.
Before I run this new node, everything looks good. However, when I run my odometry node, and broadcast the tf odom to base_link, all other transforms to base_link disappear.

I have searched the internet a lot but I can't find how to fix this issue.

Here is what I have in my node (simplified for posting here):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import traceback

from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster


class CalculatedNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('calculated_node')
        # Create publisher
        self.calculated_node = self.create_publisher(Odometry, '/odom', 10)
        self.odom_tf_broadcaster = TransformBroadcaster(self)

        # Subscribe to node
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            JointState,
            '/joint_states',
            self.update_odom,
            1)

    def update_odom(self, msg):
        try:
            # DO THE ODOM CALCULATIONS (using data from the /joint_states topic)
            # [...]
            # Broadcast the transform
            odom_trans = TransformStamped()
            self.odom_tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans)
            # Publish Odom
            self.calculated_node.publish(Odometry())
        except Exception as e: 
            traceback.print_exc()
            print(self.get_clock().now())
            # print(e)
        

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    calculate_odom = CalculatedNode()

    try:
        rclpy.spin(calculate_odom)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    calculate_odom.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transforms were not really disappearing. rqt_topic was just not refreshing enough. The mistake I was making is out of the scope of this question so it's not worth describing it in here.